# Comparing multiple lists and declaring winner based on list place

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a simple program which allows me to input the ranked position for students in a class based on their test results. Each students data is added to their own list and then the total ranked positions for each student are summed, the one with the highest overall ranking then needs to be declared the winner. If two or more students have the same overall ranking I then want to check how many top rankings they have and declare the one with the most the winner and if they are the same go to second place ranking etc until a winner is declared and if it cant be then a draw is shown. I have been able to create the lists and rank them but not do the comparative element of rankings.

My code thus far is below.

```
#A list per stud which keeps track of their grades
stud1 = []
stud2 = []
stud3 = []
stud4 = []
stud5 = []

#A list to save all of the studs names
studList = []

#List to keep all of the studs total scores
totalscores = []

#A list to concatenate the studs names and their total scores
stud1name_score =[]
stud2name_score =[]
stud3name_score =[]
stud4name_score =[]
stud5name_score =[]

#Ranked list for stud names and scores.
leaderboard=[]


#Loops 5 times and asks the user to input studs names and saves them to the studList
for i in range(1,6):
            name = input("Please enter the name of student " + str(i) + " ")
            newstud = (name)
            studList.append(newstud)


#Checks if the user has more ballot papers to input, also assigns input value to each studs list
enterMore = "y"
while(enterMore == "y"):

    stud1_grade = int(input("Type in a grade for" + " " +studList[0] ))
    stud1.append(stud1_grade)

    stud2_grade = int(input("Type in a grade for" + " " +studList[1] ))
    stud2.append(stud2_grade)

    stud3_grade = int(input("Type in a grade for" + " " +studList[2] ))
    stud3.append(stud3_grade)

    stud4_grade = int(input("Type in a grade for" + " " +studList[3] ))
    stud4.append(stud4_grade)

    stud5_grade = int(input("Type in a grade for" + " " +studList[4] ))
    stud5.append(stud5_grade)

    enterMore = input("Enter another paper? yes/no ")

print ( stud1, stud2, stud3, stud4, stud5)

#Count of the number of each grade rank the stud has, including ranking the number of 1's, 2's, 3's etc.
stud1_grade1 = stud1.count(1)
stud1_grade2 = stud1.count(2)
stud1_grade3 = stud1.count(3)
stud1_grade4 = stud1.count(4)
stud1_grade5 = stud1.count(5)
stud1_ballot_rank = [stud1_grade1, stud1_grade2, stud1_grade3, stud1_grade4, stud1_grade5]

stud2_grade1 = stud2.count(1)
stud2_grade2 = stud2.count(2)
stud2_grade3 = stud2.count(3)
stud2_grade4 = stud2.count(4)
stud2_grade5 = stud2.count(5)
stud2_ballot_rank = [stud2_grade1, stud2_grade2, stud2_grade3, stud2_grade4, stud2_grade5]

stud3_grade1 = stud3.count(1)
stud3_grade2 = stud3.count(2)
stud3_grade3 = stud3.count(3)
stud3_grade4 = stud3.count(4)
stud3_grade5 = stud3.count(5)
stud3_ballot_rank = [stud3_grade1, stud3_grade2, stud3_grade3, stud3_grade4, stud3_grade5]

stud4_grade1 = stud4.count(1)
stud4_grade2 = stud4.count(2)
stud4_grade3 = stud4.count(3)
stud4_grade4 = stud4.count(4)
stud4_grade5 = stud4.count(5)
stud4_ballot_rank = [stud4_grade1, stud4_grade2, stud4_grade3, stud4_grade4, stud4_grade5]

stud5_grade1 = stud5.count(1)
stud5_grade2 = stud5.count(2)
stud5_grade3 = stud5.count(3)
stud5_grade4 = stud5.count(4)
stud5_grade5 = stud5.count(5)
stud5_ballot_rank = [stud5_grade1, stud5_grade2, stud5_grade3, stud5_grade4, stud5_grade5]

'''
The code below creates 5 new variables one for each stud and sums
their total ballot preferences
'''
stud1total = sum(stud1)
stud2total = sum(stud2)
stud3total = sum(stud3)
stud4total = sum(stud4)
stud5total = sum(stud5)

stud1_ballot_rank.append(studList [0])
stud1_ballot_rank.append(stud1total)
stud2_ballot_rank.append(studList [1])
stud2_ballot_rank.append(stud2total)
stud3_ballot_rank.append(studList [2])
stud3_ballot_rank.append(stud3total)
stud4_ballot_rank.append(studList [3])
stud4_ballot_rank.append(stud4total)
stud5_ballot_rank.append(studList [4])
stud5_ballot_rank.append(stud5total)

overall_rank = [stud1_ballot_rank, stud2_ballot_rank, stud3_ballot_rank, stud4_ballot_rank, stud5_ballot_rank,]



'''
This code adds each studs total ballot preference score to the
totalscores list
'''
totalscores.append(stud1total)
totalscores.append(stud2total)
totalscores.append(stud3total)
totalscores.append(stud4total)
totalscores.append(stud5total)


#Prints out the studs names and their total grades score
print ("The total number of marks for " , studList [0] , "is" , stud1total)
print ("The total number of marks for " , studList [1] , "is" , stud2total)
print ("The total number of marks for " , studList [2] , "is" , stud3total)
print ("The total number of marks for " , studList [3] , "is" , stud4total)
print ("The total number of marks for " , studList [4] , "is" , stud5total)





print(sorted(overall_rank, reverse=True))
```

Comment: Your code snippet is far too big and contains a lot of code not relevant to your question. In order to improve your chances for getting an answer, you may want to get familiar with [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

use some functions to help you out

```
def get_student():
    return input("Student Name(or blank to exit):")

def get_grades(name):
    def get_grade():
        while True:
            try: 
                return int(input("Enter Grade For %s(-1 to exit):"%name))
            except ValueError:
                 print("Error Expect An Int")
    return sum(list(iter(get_grade,-1)))
```

will get a students name and a grade, now just use them to build a new list of `[(grade,name),(grade,name),...]`

```
student_grades = [(get_grades(name),name) for name in iter(get_student,"")]
```

this leverages `iter` which can take a function that accepts no arguments, and a second argument that acts as a sentinal which will stop calling the function (simplified but thats essentially it)

now you can simply sort student_grades, using the normal sort method of python

```
sorted_grades = sorted(student_grades)
print (sorted_grades) # just for sanity

#then transpose and take the second list (the list of names)
sorted_names = zip(*sorted_grades)[-1]
print(sorted_names)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to store counts of each grade, rather than specific grades. And use `list`s (or `dict`s) for more of what you're doing. For example, if all rankings are from 1-5, then make a single `stud_grades` mapping student ID #s to a `list` of the ranking counts. For example:

```
studs = []

# Map names to numbers
for i in range(1,6):
    name = input("Please enter the name of student " + str(i) + " ")
    # Store both name and list of ranking counts
    studs.append((name, [0] * 5))

enterMore = "y"
while enterMore == "y":

    for name, rankings in studs:
        rank = int(input("Type in a grade for {}".format(name)))
        rankings[rank] += 1

    enterMore = input("Enter another paper? yes/no ")

# Higher rankings better, and the sum of rankings equals overall rank
studs.sort(key=lambda x: sum(x[0]), reverse=True)

for rank, (name, rankings) in enumerate(studs, start=1):
    print("{} is ranked #{} with total score {}".format(name, rank, sum(rankings)))
```

This omits a lot of your code, but it should give you the idea. If you need to handle X number of things, it's a lot easier to use one or more `list`s of size X instead of X variables that differ only in a number in their name (if you ever see that pattern, you probably wanted a `list`).